# Extract the string in each line in a text file and count the occurrence of that string in the file

Tags: string, perl

I have a log file with sample output as below. I want to extract the value of string starting with k= in each line using Perl and then count the frequency of that string in the full log file.

```
ThreadDistributor Dispatch k='/678605358297;type=F', i=2
ThreadDistributor Dispatch k='/678605358297;type=W', i=0
ThreadDistributor Dispatch k='/678605358297;type=W', i=1
```

Expected Result:

```
k='/678605358297;type=F' occurs 1 times
k='/678605358297;type=W' occurs 2 times
```

This is what I have tried thus far:

```
use Test::More qw(no_plan);

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;
my @key;
my @keystrings;

open (INFILE, "1.txt") or die "ERROR:cannot open test result file $!";
foreach my $line (<INFILE>) {

    @key = split(' ',$line);
    push @keystrings, $key[2]

}

print "$key[2]\n";


my %counts;
$counts{$_}++ for @keystrings;
print Dumper(\%counts);

close INFILE;
```

Comment: what you tried so far.?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to grab the string you care about, and a hash to count the occurrences.  Save the following as count.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $leader = 'ThreadDistributor Dispatch';
my %dispatch_types;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    next unless m|^$leader|; # Ignore anything else
    my ($type) = m|^$leader (k=\'.+?\'),|;
    defined $type
        or die "Invalid row : '$_'";
    # print "Type is $type\n";
    $dispatch_types{$type}++;
}

for my $type ( sort keys %dispatch_types ) {
    print "$type occurs " . $dispatch_types{$type} . " times\n";
}
```

And run it as:

```
cat my_log_file | count.pl

k='/678605358297;type=F' occurs 1 times
k='/678605358297;type=W' occurs 2 times
```